# Disable Submit Button when picture is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function where users can upload photos. After uploading, the user is able to view the photos.

The submit button *should be disabled when the photo is displayed.*

I have two controller pages: photo list page and upload page.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<button class="btn" id="submit"> Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#submit").click(function () {           
         button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');           
     });
   })
```

Comment: possibly missing variable `button` declaration

Comment: can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is because on `click` of `submit` button your page got refreshed .

Correct way is to `disable` the `button` if `image` is displayed.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   if(imageDisplayed){         
      button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');           
   )
 })
```

Comment: for the "imageDisplayed", do I have to declare it?

Comment: Yes you can check that HTML part where image is display or can keep any flag for this.

Comment: for that can you share your html and image display code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> with Javascript

```
<button id="button" onclick="disable()">Click</button>
<script>
function disable() {
   document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

> with JQuery

```
<button id="button" onclick="disable()">Click</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
       $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
 });
</script>
```

This is checked codes and working perfectly.

Comment: but this is for upload photos

Comment: Just add an id to the button add use it and change the id names in the code. That is it!